# Tokbox Error ListDictionaryInternal thows message "Error with request submission"

Tags: .net, exception, error-handling, oncreate, tokbox

We are facing intermittent errors. Exception is "Error with request submission"

It happens on onCreate method.

```
session = openTok.CreateSession("", (callmode == callmode_auto ? MediaMode.ROUTED:MediaMode.RELAYED)).Id;
```

Following Tokbox SDK, it is launched here:

https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-.NET-SDK/blob/c27f590dfe383bc37c0352882262a6cc34aff05f/OpenTok/Util/HttpClient.cs#L131

Stacktrace:

```
OpenTokSDK.Exception.OpenTokWebException: Error with request submission
   in OpenTokSDK.Util.HttpClient.DoRequest(String url, Dictionary`2 specificHeaders, Dictionary`2 bodyData)
   in OpenTokSDK.OpenTok.CreateSession(String location, MediaMode mediaMode, ArchiveMode archiveMode)
```

Error data: `System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal`

It happens in production, not on the test server. I think it happens because there are some users who are creating few sessions and somehow, it breaks the system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a problem with the local time of the server. Our server was few minutes late and TokBox SDK crashed when he had to compare with local time.

Update the server clock to real time, moving it few minutes ahead, solved the problem.